# How do I display the latest unicode emojis in chrome for windows?

Tags: google-chrome, unicode

unicode 13 and country flags are not supported by chrome. zero width joiners are partially supported

test characters

Smiling Face with Tear

Disguised Face

Pinched Fingers

Anatomical Heart

Lungs

‍ Person: Dark Skin Tone, Red Hair

‍ Person: Dark Skin Tone, Curly Hair

‍ Person: Dark Skin Tone, White Hair

‍ Person: Dark Skin Tone, Bald